# jQuery AJAX simple PHP Post not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, ripple

I've got a very basic one today! I'm trying to post from jQuery to a PHP file hosted on localhost.

My JS:

```
$("#searchNameButton").click(function() {
var name = $("#searchNameText").val();
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'localhost:8080/getNameInfo.php', // -> this works fine from the browser
        // data: { name: name }, -> commented out
        success: function(){
            alert('request successful');
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('request failed');
        }
  })
});
```

My PHP file (getNameInfo.php), a very basic one for testing:

```
<?php
  echo 'TEST';
?>
```

In jQuery, it will always bring me to error, saying 'Internal Server Error'.
I am using Ripple Emulator and this is what appears in the console:

> POST https://rippleapi.herokuapp.com/xhr_proxy?tinyhippos_apikey=ABC&tinyhippos_rurl=localhost%3A8080/getNameInfo.php
>   500 (Internal Server Error)

I assume it has to do more with this than with what's written in the files. Any advice? Thanks!

**EDIT:** Found this: [LINK](http://michaelngblog.blogspot.ro/2014/01/ripple-emulator-500-internal-server.html) but it won't fix my issue. If I do what it says here, I won't get any error thrown ("" instead) but will still fail.

**EDIT 2:** If I set Cross-Domain Proxy to Local in Ripple (that's suggested in the link above) I get

> OPTIONS http://localhost:4400/ripple/xhr_proxy?tinyhippos_apikey=ABC&tinyhippos_rurl=http%3A//localhost%3A8080/getNameInfo.php net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

**EDIT 3**: Changed my URL to local

> C://Mobile//Cross-Platform//TestApp//www//php//getNameInfo.php

and it's working now. Have no idea how to make it work on localhost. BUt will go with this now, as it's only a learning app.

Comment: What is `ripplepi.herokuapp.com`? I think you may need to include `http://` before your URL.

Comment: Nope, not working. That's the call made from Ripple Emulator.

Comment: No need of localhost:8080/getNameInfo.php just give simple getNameInfo.php if both pages present in same directory

Comment: 500 response code means PHP fatal error in most cases. Check your php error log.

Comment: As I mentioned above, the URL works okay if accessed directly from browser. I guess it has something to do with how Ripple Emulator works. Please see the Console errors I get above (edited original message).

Comment: For simulation you can try postman from chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a header access control at top of `getNameInfo.php` file :

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Answer (score 0):

So, finally I found a solution.
Even though it's not a recommended one, running Chrome with

> --disable-web-security

will allow me to call a PHP script hosted on *localhost:8080* from *localhost:3000* where PhoneGap / Ripple Emulator stays.